# How do I avoid a partial upgrade?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, update-manager, partial-upgrade

I remember back in 2012, when I tried to upgrade to `Oneric` using `Software Updater`, I got something called a partial upgrade and it was a mess to deal with.

Is there any way to avoid that from happening now that I want to upgrade to `Bionic`?

I have safety measures such as having backups, and separate home partition.

Comment: Actually I would rather use a live disk of `Bionic` to perform the upgrade, to be on the safe side. I forgot that was an option. I will close the question soon unless I get an upvote.